# whether the function is injective surjective or both

Tags: functions, injective-module

> Let $f: \mathbb R^2\to\mathbb R$ be defined by $f(x,y)=x^2+y^3,$ then is it injective bijective or both?

I try this:
if $x_1^2+y_1^3=x_2^2+y_2^3$, it doesn't mean $x_2=x_1, y_2=y_1$. So it is not injective.

Am I correct?

Comment: Your justification is: it isn't injective, so it isn't injective...

Comment: I don't see any argument here.  To show it is not injective, all you have to do is to find $(a,b)\neq (c,d)$ with $f(a,b)=f(c,d)$.  This should not be difficult.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).  Cf. [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3566172/injective-and-surjective-function-of-fx-y)

Answer (score 1):

The function is a surjection (not an injection):

Proof that it's not an injection: $f(1,0)=f(-1,0)=1$.

Proof it's a surjection: $f(0,\sqrt[3]x)=x$ for all $x\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: So if (x1,y1) not equal to (x2,y2), but f(x1,y1)=f(x2,y2), then it is not injection,..can x,y be any numer (rational, irrational?)

Comment: $(x,y)$ is in the domain of $f$.

Comment: RIght....I grasped the idea just now. May I know how your proof of surjection works? Thanks!

Comment: For any $x$ in the range, there is some tuple in the domain that maps to $x$. I showed that $(0,\sqrt[3]x)$ maps to $x$, regardless of what $x$ is.

Comment: I'm a bit slow on maths,,,do we care about y also?